# Javascript - check for variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is a very nooby question for which answer I searched way too long while not finding anything.
I'm not used to javascript but other programming languages so, how does it work if you want something to be constantly checked for?

Here my code:

```
var test = 0;

$( ".test_div" ).click(function() {
    test = 1;
});
```

Now if I want to check if the variable is 1, constantly, what do I do? 
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if (test == 1) { }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't *constantly* check something as javascript runs on a single thread (if you do something without pause, nothing else will run), but you can check it *regularly*. Look into the setInterval function, or Object.observe as recommended below.

Comment: Do take into consideration that the Object.observe function is *experimental*, it might not be compatible with all the browsers...

Comment: Explain **CONSTANTLY**

Comment: I see! Thanks everyone.
@Mr. Alien - Well, I thought of it more like Java, in which it's running through the whole code all the time, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @wupto please don't mix up java and js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are searching for something do be done in an `interval`

Following could help you:

```
var test = 0;
var interval;

function check_test() {
    if( test == 1 ){
        clearInterval( interval );
        console.log( "Test is 1 now!" );
    }
}

interval = window.setInterval( check_test, 1000 );
```

The `1000` is in milliseconds, so 1000 ms = 1 second.
This will call `check_test()` every 1sec.

You also could do `window.setTimeout` in a simmiliar way, but this will do it just one time. Than you could call it inside the function again and if you want to stop it, you just stop calling it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome or Opera, have a look at Javascript `Object.observe()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

If you need something less bleeding-edge, you would need to use a framework (such as Angular, although others are available) where you can set watches on variables.

Comment: ...or `setInterval` as a dirty workaround, as Doldt suggested in comments.

Comment: Where is your sense of adventure? :o)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can check if the value has changed.

Using setInterval method:

```
    var test = 0; // initial value
    var checkInterval = 1000; // time in millisecond, 1000 = 1 second

    setInterval(function() {
        if(test !== 0) { // check if test is not equal to initial value
            console.log("Test value changed! New value: "+test);
        }
    }, checkInterval);
```

The above code will test the condition every 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take you a little bit back, do you really need to check it constantly? even if there are known specific events when it's value can be changed? I think it depends on your needs.

First of all, I would consider [Pub/Sub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) or [Observer](https://carldanley.com/js-observer-pattern/) patterns, they would be definitely more efficient and reliable than running a special interval each X milliseconds.