# Trigger a js function on orientationchangeend inside svelte:body

Tags: javascript, viewport, svelte

I want to display a message with a black background whenever the viewport orientation is portrait mode in svelte.

I used [svelte-viewport-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-viewport-info) to get the orientation of the viewport.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Viewport from 'svelte-viewport-info'
  console.log('standard Screen Orientation: ',Viewport.Orientation)
</script>

<svelte:body
  on:orientationchangeend={() => { console.log(
    'Screen Orientation changed to: ', Viewport.Orientation + (
      Viewport.detailledOrientation == null
      ? ''
      : '(' + Viewport.detailledOrientation + ')'
    )
  ) }}
/>
```

I want to change the `display` property of a `div`

- When in `landscape mode`, `display` set to `none`
- When in `portrait mode`, `display` set to `block`

I found a `js` syntax [to call function after a certain amount of time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118837/javascript-check-for-variable/?#answer-30118913)

```
var test = 0;
var interval;

function check_test() {
    if( test == 1 ){
        clearInterval( interval );
        console.log( "Test is 1 now!" );
    }
}

interval = window.setInterval( check_test, 1000 );
```

So inside this above function that is called every 1000 millisecond/1 second.

I found a syntax to use `if` statement in svelte here in [#template-syntax-if](https://svelte.dev/docs?#template-syntax-if)

How do I perform all this in svelte it's along confusing

1. I have to repeatedly call function using **window.setInterval** after certain interval
2. Function needs to check the viewport Orientation from **on:orientationchangeend inside svelte:body**
3. Use the **if in svelte** to **set the display property of a div to block or none depending on the viewport Orientation from step 2**

Comment: What about your task is confusing?  "I want to change the display property of a div" - why are you not changing the display property of a div? The "interval" code you found is noise, forget about that. You  don't want to do that on an interval. You want to do that on the `orientationchangeend` event. You already have all the code you need. Your remaining question has precisely nothing to do with svelte. You're asking "how can I set the display property on a div" and that should not to be too hard to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the svelte-viewport-info [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-viewport-info#css-classes)

> **CSS Classes**
> In addition, the package also adds or removes the following CSS classes depending on the current device orientation:
> **Portrait** - indicates that the device is currently in any "Portrait" orientation
> **Landscape** - indicates that the device is currently in any "Landscape" orientation

So you don't even have to track any event, you can simply use these classes to change the display of the div >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ea80b88d98604714877a5049ac26fcb7?version=3.46.3)
(The compiler doesn't see any elements with the classes `Landscape` and `Portrait`, so the [`:global()` modifier](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-style) must be added so that they get compiled)

```
<script context="module">
    import Viewport from 'svelte-viewport-info'
</script>

<div class="only-portrait">
    only visible in Portrait Mode
</div>

<style>
    :global(.Landscape .only-portrait) {
        display: none;
    }
    :global(.Portrait .only-portrait) {
        display: block;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        padding: 2rem;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I need to reduce the size of an image when `screen height` is `133%` of screen `width` or `less`. How do I do it?

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth better you post a new question for this with a detailed explanation

Comment: here is the question [Dynamically detection of screen height and screen width to change the height and width of an image in svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70983393/dynamically-detection-of-screen-height-and-screen-width-to-change-the-height-and)