# Dynamically detection of screen height and screen width to change the height and width of an image in svelte

Tags: jquery, css, svelte

I was able to `display` a `div` tag only in `portrait` using the code below as mentioned by [corrl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15388872/corrl) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70922264/trigger-a-js-function-on-orientationchangeend-inside-sveltebody?#answer-70922807) post response

```
<script context="module">
    import Viewport from 'svelte-viewport-info'
</script>

<div class="only-portrait">
    only visible in Portrait Mode
</div>

<style>
    :global(.Landscape .only-portrait) {
        display: none;
    }
    :global(.Portrait .only-portrait) {
        display: block;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        padding: 2rem;
    }
</style>
```

Worked as intended

But one of image elements dimension(height and width) needs to reduce in `portrait` mode when the dimension of the viewport to be more specific is `height.viewport <= 133% of width.viewport`

[image]

I tried to get the `viewport` `height` and `width` using  code from [Inner and Outer window bindings](https://svelte.dev/repl/867c433fd36a463fa5bb257cec2c1766?version=3.35.0)

```
<script>
    $: outerWidth = 0
    $: outerHeight = 0
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth bind:outerWidth bind:innerHeight bind:outerHeight />
```

Tried using jquery to change the width and height of image based on condition `viewport.width*1.33 <= viewport.height`

imported jquery as mentioned [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/355398c8d6bd4081980ed2abfc5f4286?version=3.9.2)

```
<script lang="ts">
  import jQuery from 'jquery';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  onMount(() => {
    window.jQuery = jQuery;
    
  jQuery(window).resize(function(event){
  console.log(outerWidth*1.33,' ',outerHeight);
  if(outerWidth*1.33 <= outerHeight) {
   jQuery(".imageclass").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).attr("width", "78vw");  jQuery(this).attr("height", "78vw/2.81vh");
  });} 

  });

});
</script>
<svelte:window  bind:outerWidth bind:outerHeight />
```

I am getting this error

> File: /home/Documents/sve/svelteDemo/src/App.svelte   29 |
> import { MetaTags } from 'svelte-meta-tags';   30 |  import
> 'svelte-viewport-info';   31 |  import jQuery from 'jquery';
> |                      ^   32 |  import { onMount } from 'svelte';   33 |  import image1v from './assets/image1.png';
> at formatError (/home/Documents/sve/svelteDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:36769:46)
> at TransformContext.error (/home/Documents/sve/svelteDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:36765:19)
> at normalizeUrl (/home/Documents/sve/svelteDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:73703:26)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async TransformContext.transform (/home/Documents/sve/svelteDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:73843:57)
> at async Object.transform (/home/Documents/sve/svelteDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:36985:30)
> at async doTransform (/home/Documents/sve/svelteDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-f5552faa.js:52060:29)

Don't seem to understand what is going wrong here!

How to make this work? or is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: It's possible to bind the windows width and height by using the special `svelte:window` component. Here is an example: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-window-bindings

Comment: @johannchopin Tried using it, having the above issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As proposed in the comments you can use bindings inside `<svelte:window>` to track the size. (Note that the variables are just declared `let innerHeight = 0`, they don't need `$:`)
Then you can declare a reactive variable (here the `$:`) based on the two values  which results to `true` or `false` based on the condition you're after.
For resizing the image you can again use a class and the [`class:` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name) so the class is added if the condition is `true`. (Note that the declaration of the conditional class must come **after** the basic class inside the `<style>` tag or stylesheet, so the values get overwritten.)

Here's the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5e8a5f2e56184615a0bbd128d31a6cf6?version=3.46.4)

```
<script>
    let innerWidth = 0
    let innerHeight = 0
    
    $: condition = innerWidth*1.33 <= innerHeight
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth bind:innerHeight />

<p> Inner Width: {innerWidth} </p>
<p> Inner Height: {innerHeight} </p>
<p> condition: {condition} </p>

<img src="https://svelte.dev/svelte-logo-horizontal.svg" alt=""
         class="image-basic"
         class:image-conditional={condition}
         />

<style>
    .image-basic {
        width: 100vw;
    }
    .image-conditional {
        width: 50vw;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: I had to reverse the condition to `condition = outerWidth*1.33 >= outerHeight` to get the desired result weird.

Comment: You should start a tutorial on YouTube for svelte, to make it easy for beginners. At least the basics part, if the official or unofficial examples were simple enough for a new person like me to understand, I wouldn't have posted it here.

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth I prefer helping out with concrete problems :) And while I agree, that some examples might be a bit more complex than they probably need to and so are maybe not completely beginner friendly, the [official tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics) is still a very good place to learn Svelte. Just check back now and then and things will become clearer with time... (that's what I experienced)